# How to Disavow Bad Backlinks Automatically?

Tags: seo, search-engines

I have this website which is relatively new and I am trying to rank it in Google. But, I have this enemy who keeps building bad/spam links to my site. So, every time I see some rank improvement in my site, he builds spam links to my site and my ranking slides down in SERP's.
I am disavowing those links as soon as I see them but, for how much time I am gonna do that!
Is there any tool or trick using which I can disavow such links automatically?

Comment: Are these links always from different domains?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes. Always different domains. I disavow them and new backlinks are addered on new domains.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to disavow the links automatically. In that case there is a chance to disavow quality link.

Comment: Lot's of talking about disavow backlinks. The latest animals of the Google Zoo simply will not take in account bad links. They know you received without knowing. My back links fluctuate from 14,000 to 900 and back to 14,000, most is garbage. Panda and friends know it, don't spend time disavow.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to disavow links automatically, you can only manually disavow them or do so using the Google Disavow Tool.